# Zeros of primitive functions of S

Tags: nt.number-theory

Hello,

I would like to know whether there are known examples of primitive functions of the Selberg class having at least one non simple non trivial zero or not.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: As in the examples given below, this should only ever happen at $s=1/2$.

Comment: Do you mean that whatever the primitive function of the Selberg class, $s=1/2$ is the only possible non simple non trivial zero?

Comment: By the way, I would like to know whether the following statement is true or not:
"for all positive integer $d$, there is a primitive function of the Selberg class of degree $d$ all the non trivial zeros of which are simple".
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

There is an example given in this paper:

J. P. Buhler, B. H. Gross, and D. B. Zagier, "On the Conjecture of Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer for an Elliptic Curve of Rank 3," *Mathematics of Computation* **44** (1985), no. 170, pp. 473-481.

http://www.jstor.org/stable/2007967

Answer (score 3):

Any $L$-function of a (modular) elliptic curve of analytic rank $\geq2$, such as Cremona's curve '389a', will have a non-trivial double zero at $s=1$. More generally, the $L$-function of any irreducible cuspidal automorphic representation of $GL(2,\mathbf{Q})$ for which the Ramanajuan conjecture holds (such as holomorphic cusp forms) is a primitive element of the Selberg class (a result of Ram Murty's [MR1354178](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1354178)).